# Display image when preview button is click before upload in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML form like this:

```
     <form id="myForm" name="myform" action="register/index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

<input class="myfile" id="banner" name="banner" type="file" accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg" >

<a href="#" onclick="getPreview();>Preview</a>

 <input type="submit"  value="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

What I want to do is when a user clicks on the preview button his chosen file will display somewhere in `<div id="myid"></div>`

```
<script>

function getPreview(){

// what should write here to make this working
}

</script>
```

Anyone please help in this, how to do this using jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded

Comment: i have edited your code in my answer as per your requirement, when you click on preview, then your image will be displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, may be this will help, else you can customize more as per your requirement

```js
function readURL(input) {  
   $('.preview').show();
  $('#blah').hide();
  $('.preview').after('<img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" style="display:none;"/>');
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $('#blah')
      .attr('src', e.target.result)
      .width(150)
      .height(200);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

function getPreview(){
  $('.preview').hide();
  $('#blah').show();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
      <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
   </div>
  <div>
  <a href="#" class="preview" onclick="getPreview();">Preview</a><br/>   
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how can i dynamically create img tag then display this image in, like i have i div that have some text and i want to remove that text and place this image.

Comment: you asking me to remove preview text after clicking the link to show image?

Comment: yes, and also when new image is choosed the old image should gone

Comment: try now again my code, i have changed the code as you asked to do.

Comment: Thank You so much , working now exactly as i want.

Comment: always...Happy coding

Comment: It's better to use `URL.createObjectURL`